How to deal with extremely out of date questions
I recently was searching around to see if there had been any discussion on what I thought was a strange "feature" of django, and my DuckDuckGo query gave as the first result this question. It looked like perhaps it was related to my issue so I clicked through to it and after a couple of minutes reading I realised that not only was it not at all related, but it was 15 years old and about a long-fixed bug in a development version of django. But here we are in 2024 and it is being presented as the first result in web searches for superficially similar topics.
I struggle to see how this question and answer could give any value to anyone today, given as I say it was a question about a bug in a development version that has since been fixed. Can I do something about this? Basically I want this not to appear in search results! My options seem to be

edit the question to say prominently at the top that it is out of date so that people finding it who won't be looking for the same issue can quickly ignore it
down vote it so maybe it becomes less prioritised in search results
vote to close it
flag it in some way
nothing and get on with my life!

I personally feel that closing it feels like the right thing as I assume that means it will no longer be found in searches, and my aim is to make this never show up in search results again! Is there a standard procedure for such questions?
This is similar to this question but I think it is different because that is about questions that are out of date but may still be useful, whereas this is about questions that are so out of date / specific to an old development version that I believe they will never be useful to anyone again.

"down vote it so maybe it becomes less prioritised in search results" votes have no bearing on search engine results. They just bring relevant matches but have no concept of a site-specific mechanism like votes. Remember that search engines service the entire Internet. "I personally feel that closing it feels like the right thing as I assume that means it will no longer be found in searches" see what I already explained about search engines being generic, not keyed on SO/SE specific features.

On another note: just because you don't benefit from the question, doesn't mean nobody would. It could be that some poor soul has to maintain very outdated technology. And 15 years is not even that old even among "old tech" circles. It's also possible that people have use of this information for history purposes, rather than something they face today. These considerations might not always have much relevance, however, still useful to consider. Rather than directly going to "I don't find use for this - remove it".

There was briefly a push by the company to deal with outdated answers, but it was abandoned in favour of AI and other meaningless hype projects no one asked for. The answer, unfortunately, is that there's nothing we can do. We lack the moderator and curator capacity to manually deal with it, and without system-sided support to help, doing anything is a sisyphean task.

I've changed the question around a bit and also updated the title so it is very obvious that it's about a specific version, hopefully that would improve the search results.

If you didn’t find the question helpful downvote it, but there is absolutely I reason, to do anything other than that.

You could try using a different Q&A site such as Codidact, which has a feature for explicitly marking such questions.

Questions on Stack Overflow are never really out of date. Unless you make the assumption that everyone runs on properly upgraded versions. The truth of it more is that they are less relevant to you... for now and I hope it stays that way. It's not a property of the question, it's a property of your user account which must somehow dictate this.

I edit a post or comment it to make it clear what version the  post is about.
Please do not downvote/change a post only because the issue is related to old software. There is a lot of legacy code/old systems that have to be maintained to this day, Q&As relating to them still have a lot of value.
If there happens to be a similar but distinct issue in a newer version you could add a new, version specific question.
